# Reverse color mapping in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a set of numbers from 1 to 100 -- they're rankings, so 1 is greater than 2 (30 is greater than 100, etc.)

This is my color function right now:

```
var color = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, 100])
            .range(colorbrewer.Reds[3]);
```

Except this maps 1's and 2's as the lighter shades or Red.

Any ideas how to go about this? I think my terminology (reverse? inverse color mapping?) is incorrect because I can't find this in the documentation.

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried simply reversing the domain values? EDIT: just saw your answer, glad you figured it out yourself :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

D'oh.

Reverse the domain .....

```
var color = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([100, 0])
            .range(colorbrewer.Reds[3]);
```

YOLO